# Is there a Graph theory way to solve this iteration problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This thought came when i was trying to find the number of functions $f(x)$ from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that satisfy $f(f(x)) = f(f(f(x)))$ for all $x$ in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  What i did was took cases when only one , two...etc  values of x such that all those are identity functions from that i got the answer as 756 which is correct.  But i was thinking if there was some kind of GT use can be done here  which can solve it more easily than case bash?

Comment: You can make a directed graph, with an edge $x\to f(x)$ for each $x$. If you ignore any edges of the form $x\to x$, you can this graph is a rooted forest where every tree has depth at most $2$. I am not sure this makes it much easier to count, though

Comment: Can caseys theorem help here to get the required number of forests by removing the unwanted trees?

Comment: I am not sure. Cayley's formula implies the number of rooted forests is $6^4=1296$. You would then need to subtract out all rooted forests with a depth of three or more, of which there are apparently $540$. But counting those seems like just as much of a bash.

Comment: Hmm yeah seems like Sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give a strategy that generalizes using generating functions. As Mike Earnest points out, we want to count rooted labelled forests of size $5$ with depth at most $2$. Let's find the EGF of such forests of size $n$.

A tree is a root with a set of trees attached. Let $\mathcal T^{(2)}$ be the class of trees of depth at most $2$, and let $\mathcal Z$ denote a node. Then using the symbolic method we have
$$
\mathcal T^{(2)} = \mathcal Z\star SET(\mathcal Z\star SET(\mathcal Z))
$$
(Each use of $SET$ correspond to a possible layer). A forest is just a set of trees, so we get the following EGF
$$
\mathcal F^{(2)} = SET(\mathcal T^{(2)})
\implies F^{(2)}(z) = \exp(z\exp(z\exp(z)))
$$
The number of these forests that have $n$ nodes is then given by $F_n^{(2)} = n![z^n]F^{(2)}(z)$, where $[z^n]$ means the coefficient at $z^n$ in the series expansion of the EGF. We find
$$ \begin{split}
F^{(2)}(z) &= \exp(z\exp(z\exp(z))) \\
&= \sum_{m\ge0}\frac{z^me^{mze^z}}{m!}\\
&= \sum_{m\ge0}\frac{z^m}{m!} \sum_{k\ge0}\frac{m^kz^ke^{kz}}{k!}\\
&= \sum_{m\ge0}\frac{z^m}{m!} \sum_{k\ge0}\frac{m^kz^k}{k!}  \sum_{j\ge0}\frac{k^jz^j}{j!}\\
&= \sum_{m,k,j\ge0}\frac{m^kk^j}{m!k!j!}z^{m+k+j}\\
&= \sum_{n\ge0} \left(\sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} \frac{m^kk^{n-m-k}}{m!k!(n-m-k)!}\right)z^n
\end{split}$$
So our final answer is
$$
F_n^{(2)} = n! \sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} \frac{m^kk^{n-m-k}}{m!k!(n-m-k)!}
$$
and we can verify that $F_5^{(2)}$ is indeed $756$ using this formula. You can find the sequence at [A949](http://oeis.org/A000949) on OEIS. I don't know if we can do much more than this, other than cleaning up the edge cases and perhaps rewriting with a trinomial coefficient:
$$
F_n^{(2)} = 1 + \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-m}\binom{n}{m,k,n-m-k} m^kk^{n-m-k}
$$

Answer (score 3):

The best I can give is a generating function solution, which gives a way to count such graphs automatically with a computer.

If you make a directed graph with an edge $x\to f(x)$ for each $x\in \{1,\dots,5\}$, and ignore any self loops $x\to x$, what remains is a rooted forest where each tree has depth at most $2$. If we let $F_{h,n}$ be the number of rooted forests on $n$ vertices with a depth of at most $h$, and $F_h(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}F_{h,n}x^n$ be the exponential generating function, then
$$
F_h(x)=\exp(x F_{h-1}(x))
$$
This is because a rooted forest is given by partitioning the underlying set ($\exp$), choosing a root for each set $(x)$, and then putting a rooted forest structure with depth $h-1$ on the remaining elements of each set $F_{h-1}(x)$. In your case, we get
$$
F_2(x)=\exp(xF_1(x))=\exp(x\exp(xF_0(x)))=\exp(x\exp (x\exp(x)))
$$
Therefore, it follows that
$$
F_{2,n}=n![x^n]\exp(x\exp (x\exp(x)))
$$
where $[x^n]f(x)$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series $f(x)$. For example, the Mathematica code

```
5! * SeriesCoefficent[ Exp[x Exp[x Exp[x]]], {x, 0, 5}]
```

verifies your count of $756$, as shown on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%21+*+SeriesCoefficent%5B+Exp%5Bx+Exp%5Bx+Exp%5Bx%5D%5D%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+n%7D%5D+where+n+%3D+5).

Comment: Oops, you beat me to it.

Comment: @Milten I prefer the exposition in your answer, and the summation formula you derived gives a pretty doable way to evaluate the number by hand.

Comment: From both of your methods i got a method which is not lengthy and bashy respected Milten Sir and Mike Earnest Sir , should i post it as a answer to my own query ?

Comment: @WizardMath I would be very interested in seeing it!

Comment: I shared , pls comment if its all gud or something is missing :)

Answer (score 2):

From @Mike Earnest and @Milten approaches, now I am considering a graph on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ made by placing an arrow from $i$ to $j$ if $f(i)=j$, and removing all self-loops. Absolutely we can have no cycles, so this graph is in fact a forest. Adding a vertex $r$ to the graph and having all roots of trees in this graph (that is, $i$ with $f(i)=i$) point to $r$. Then what we want to count is trees on $\{1,2,3,4,5,r\}$ with every vertex a distance of at most $3$ from $r$ (this is equivalent by directing all edges towards $r$). Ignoring the distance condition, Cayley's formula gives that there are $6^4=1296$ trees. We now must subtract the trees with at least one vertex of distance $4$ from $r$. Such trees will have a "backbone" of $5$ consecutive vertices ending at $r$ (say $v_4,v_3,v_2,v_1,r$) and then the 6th vertex will have one of these as its parent. If the parent is $r,v_1,v_2,v_4$ there are $5!$ trees each, and if the parent is $v_3$ there will be $\frac{5!}{2}$ because the 6th vertex and $v_4$ can be swapped. Hence required answer is $1296-120\cdot 4-60 = 756$.

Comment: That all checks out, nicely done :^)

Comment: Ty Sir:) , now i am just thinking whose answer i should tick mark it as only one answer can be choosen according to the system here in MSE

Comment: Nice :) You are free to accept your own answer if you feel it matches the question best. Of course with just a few more vertices you would get more and more cases to consider again.

Comment: Hmm well said Sir 